# How to select jQuery version based on browser version without using HTML <!--[if]-->

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know how to detect different browser types and select different jQuery versions using HTML `if / endif` statements like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <script src="jQuery-1.11.x.min.js"></script> <![endif]-->
```

Now I want to support IE version < 8 using compatible version of jQuery. I also want to use jQuery 2.x.x for more modern browsers. Is there a way to use certain JavaScript library and implement this (for example requirejs or modernizr) with a single global configuration file, instead of adding HTML detection in every single page?

Comment: I'm afraid browser detection is considered bad practice. Feature detection is preferred. This is why frameworks like modernizr do not support browser detection. Try to solve your problem a different way, think outside the box. I would recommend making a decision: either your site will support IE8 or it won't. Then choose the appropriate jQuery version. Your code will be much easier to maintain. Trust me, it's not worth it.

Comment: Just use jQuery 1.x if you want to support IE8 and let Google host it for you. (http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/)

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by @CodeDreamer68 , browser detection is a bad practice. But, this might help you.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/